# Компиляция .ts в .js

Tags: javascript, typescript, компиляция

Всем доброго времени суток!
Ситуация: пишу проект на TypeScript, но для корректного запуска нужны аналогичные файлы на JavaScript. Казалось бы, скомпилируй и радуйся, но есть условия - нельзя собирать все в один bundle.js, и нужно, чтобы итоговые файлы располагались в той же иерархии в папке dist, что и исходные .ts файлы.
Помогите настроить вебпак, пожалуйста! Максимум, который у меня получился - структура файлов *.d.ts, но это не то, что мне нужно)
Благодарю за ответы)

Comment: а скомпилировать их `tsc`?

Comment: Всю сотню файлов? Вроде ж оно точечно меняет? Мне надо все разом...

Comment: всю сотню файлов. в чем проблема скомпилировать базовым компилятором?

Comment: Оп, получилось. Вот это да! Спасибо) Зациклилась на том, что так не работает) Но они собрались каждый рядом со своим исходным файлом. Как их вынести в отдельную папку? В смысле, не вручную.

Comment: tsconfig.json -> compilerOptions -> outDir или что-то вроде того, если я правильно понимаю ваш вопрос. или `tsc -p ./path/to/tsconfig.json` c указанием кастомного конфига

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо огромное! Понятно было, что вопрос пустяковый, но сколько нервов отнял...

Comment: лучше сделайте tsconfig.json файл, и в нем укажите outDir куда вам нужно. по примеру от @nörbörnën. а вообще, вот есть дока https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outDir